# Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation upon object instantiation

Tags: sharepoint, signalr, signalr.client

I've been bending my head over this problem all the afternoon to no avail. I have a requirement to integrate SignalR into a SharePoint farm solution (http://sharepoint-community.net/profiles/blogs/using-signalr-2-2-in-a-sharepoint-2013-farm-solution). The integration itself is not the issue here, once I can see the log events when consuming a custom **PersistentConnection** with JS. My company uses a service layer based on **HttpHandlers** responding to custom suffixes and executing some reflection to know which method to invoke based on the url pattern. Everything has always worked great! The problem arises when in my service code, which will be sending messages to the custom PersistentConnection so that it can broadcast to all connected clients, I instantiate a **Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Connection** object.

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client;
// other usings
[Route] // Custom attribute
public object MyCustomServiceMethod() {
    try // LINE NUMBER: 5
    {
        // broadcast message to all connected clients
        var url = "CONNECTION URL"; // LINE NUMBER 8
        var connection = new Connection(url); // LINE NUMBER: 9
        connection.Start().Wait(); // LINE NUMBER: 10
        connection.Send(CUSTOM_MODEL_HERE).Wait(); // LINE NUMBER: 11

        return Ok(new // LINE NUMBER: 13
        {
            Status = "SOME STATUS CODE HERE",
            Data = SOME DATA HERE
        });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       // some logging logic here
    }
}
```

The thing is I get an "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation." exception and execution doesn't run the **MyCustomServiceMethod** method. Funny thing is when I comment line numbers 9, 10 and 11, the execution gets to line 13 e returns perfectly. My sharepoint project compiles against .Net 4.5, so I referenced version 4.5 of SignalR Client (https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client45). when I leave the aforementioned lines uncommented, code execution doesn't even reach the breakpoint on line 5 inside my custom service method. It throws an exception before in the pipeline. What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution to the problem! The issue was that I generated the **Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.dll** from the source code downloaded directly from github, so that the generated dll wasn't signed. Once I downloaded the **Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.dll** from nuget, the code ran perfectly.